# How do I understand and fix error while compiling Linux kernel for embedded system

Tags: c, linux-kernel, makefile, arm, native

While trying to compile the following file:

```
/*
 *  linux/arch/arm/mm/proc-syms.c
 *
 *  Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Russell King
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation.
 */
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>

#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include <asm/proc-fns.h>
#include <asm/tlbflush.h>
#include <asm/page.h>

#ifndef MULTI_CPU
EXPORT_SYMBOL(cpu_dcache_clean_area);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(cpu_set_pte_ext);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(cpu_tima_set_pte_ext);
#else
EXPORT_SYMBOL(processor);
#endif

#ifndef MULTI_CACHE
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__cpuc_flush_kern_all);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__cpuc_flush_user_all);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__cpuc_flush_user_range);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__cpuc_coherent_kern_range);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__cpuc_flush_dcache_area);
#else
EXPORT_SYMBOL(cpu_cache);
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_MMU
#ifndef MULTI_USER
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__cpu_clear_user_highpage);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(__cpu_copy_user_highpage);
#else
EXPORT_SYMBOL(cpu_user);
#endif
#endif

/*
 * No module should need to touch the TLB (and currently
 * no modules do.  We export this for "loadkernel" support
 * (booting a new kernel from within a running kernel.)
 */
#ifdef MULTI_TLB
EXPORT_SYMBOL(cpu_tlb);
#endif
```

I get the following error:

```
arch/arm/mm/proc-syms.c:21:1: error: 'cpu_tima_set_pte_ext' undeclared here (not in a function)
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mm/proc-syms.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/arm/mm] Error 2
```

I am actually surprised that I get this error. This is code which I downloaded from a vendor, and I do not think it would have error in it. Is there someway to bypass this error? Is this a real error, or something which will be fixed during the link phase?

@user58697 - You d'man. Thanks. Thank you so much. This was the fastest reply and correct.

Comment: This was a known problem. A patch exists (see for example http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51760869)

Comment: @user58697 do you mind putting that up as an answer? That way it will be more visible for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:

This was a known problem. A patch exists (see for example [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51760869))